# Assembly x86 graphic mode 13h cursor placment

Tags: assembly

I am very new to assembly, and I am having trouble understanding how the cursor placement goes in mode 13h. For example, (0,0) ends up in the middle of the screen. I can't understand how to get it to be where I want.

The code I am using:

```
mov al, 13h
mov ah, 0h
int 10h
mov ax, dseg
mov ds, ax

mov dl, 0 ;row  
mov dh, 0 ;col
mov bx, 0
mov ah, 2h
int 10h
mov dx, offset string
mov ah, 9h      
int 21h

mov al, 3h
mov ah, 0h
int 10h
int 3h
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: 1988 is calling, they want their code back. :-)

Comment: yeah.. this is for school, and I can't find any explanation about it online

Comment: Mode 13h position 0,0 is the upper left corner.  I don't have my reference handy, but nothing is jumping out at me as to why you'd end up with a cursor in the middle of the screen though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I know that pain.

First of all according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H) and [this site](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-2.html) for the interrupt `int 10h` with code `AH=2h`, DL is for Columns and DH is for Rows.
Also why `int 3` at the end?

Anyway, this code works for me - it prints the string at pos 2,3. Compiled with tasm, ran under dosbox.

```
; AH=0h: Set video mode
mov al, 13h ; Video mode number
mov ah, 0h
int 10h

; AH=2h: Set cursor position
mov dl, 2 ; Column
mov dh, 3 ; Row
mov bx, 0 ; Page number, 0 for graphics modes
mov ah, 2h
int 10h

; AH=9h: Print string
mov dx, offset string
mov ah, 9h
int 21h

; Wait for keypress
mov ah, 08h
int 21h

; AH=0h: Set video mode
mov al, 3h ; Video mode number
mov ah, 0h
int 10h

; Exit
mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 0
int 21h
```

Also an advice: Write as many comments as you can; there's never too many of them in assembly ;)

Comment: Nicely written. Font size is also changed in this code. If we want to maintain the same font, < mov al, 3 > at second line.

Comment: The same code compiles with `masm` , (ofcourse, along with the headers). I have tested it under dosbox.